# Deleting an object when multiple pointers are pointing to it?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I've been told that when if I have multiple pointers pointing to the same object, I cannot delete it normally (using the delete keyword). Instead, I've been told that I need to set the pointers to NULL or 0.

Given I have:

```
ClassA* object = new ClassA();
ClassA* pointer1 = object;
ClassA* pointer2 = object;
```

So to `delete` `pointer1` and `pointer2`, do I need to do the following?

```
pointer1 = 0;
pointer2 = 0:
```

Once I've set it to NULL, do I still need to use the keyword `delete`? Or is just setting it to 0 good enough?

Comment: `delete pointer1;` or `delete pointer2;` but not both then set both pointers to 0 , you better use `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: @Kerrek I'm not sure what you mean? I'm merely saying "Setting a pointer to NULL isn't the same as deleting it.". It wasn't clear OP is aware of that.

Comment: Stop messing around with me! :)

Comment: Another way of seeing this: in C++ (unlike, say, Java or Objective-C), the compiler is not going to make any inferences from the fact that you have set a pointer to null. You need to explicitly delete the object, and setting references to null are for your program's own internal consistency/information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever you `new` an object, you need to `delete` it, free'ing the memory

```
ClassA* object = new ClassA();

delete object; // Free's the memory you allocated.
```

The point of setting your pointers to `NULL` is to stop **dereferencing** pointers that are **invalid**

```
object = NULL;
```

This is done so that tests can be performed before attempting a dereference:

```
if(object != NULL)
{
  object->SomeMethod(); // We can assume it's safe to use the pointer.
}
```

**Also note** that you can delete the memory from **any pointer** that points to it.

```
ClassA* object = new ClassA();
ClassA* pointer1 = object;
ClassA* pointer2 = object;

delete pointer1;
```

`object, pointer1, and pointer2` now **all** point to memory that has already been released, and unless they will be redefined, they should all be set to **NULL**.

Answer (score 4):

The rule is You **must** call `delete` as many times you called `new`.
So if you allocated memory only once you need to deallocate it only once too.

You can just be better off using `shared_ptr` to avoid this manual memory management, wherein the smart pointer itself will deallocate the memory once no pointer is pointing to it.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to make sure that you don't use the object anymore after deleting it. It doesn't matter whether you have pointers pointing to it, but you need to know that these pointers are now invalid. Setting them to nullptr is merely a way to get a sure crash when you use them; using invalid pointers may or may not cause a crash, but it will eventually cause obscure problems that are difficult to trace.

However, if you have "live" pointers to the object when you delete it, that MIGHT indicate a problem in your code. Usually, an object gets deleted when nobody needs it anymore, which means there SHOULD be no pointers or other references to it. This is not a hard rule, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You need to delete it and set to 0 after that, or use smart pointers

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `delete` other wise you well have a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)

Answer (score 0):

Its not You cannot `delete`. But you should not. because deleteing an already deleted oibject will crash your program. and you will see `glibc detected double free`. So the best practice if

```
if(object){
   delete object;
   object = 0;
}
```

If you don't set it to `0` or `NULL` and gaurd it win an `if` you may double delete it.

Comment: This is not "best practice". It's needlessly verbose. `delete object` already ignores null pointers, and writing `0` over `0` is equally harmless.

Answer (score 0):

The code creates the object with new; it should destroy the object with delete. Once. The fact that there are other pointers to the object doesn't matter, nor does it matter whether the code sets those pointers to 0. (Unless you're running with a garbage collector, which you're not doing). The only benefit from setting those pointers to 0 is if your program uses 0 as a flag that means no object. That's a design decision, and whether it's appropriate can't be answered from the information presented here.